# Output from multiple queries to single file with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a csv-file with multiple rows containing select statements that I would like to execute and then save all the results to one file.

Each row in the csv is looking something like this:

```
SELECT 'somehardcodedname' AS name,age FROM account WHERE id='somehardcodedid';
```

I attempted to run the following command:

```
\o output.csv
\i input.csv
```

This creates a file but the file is sort of useless, since I am getting the table names and the number of rows before/after each result and the table structure in the csv becomes ugly(kind of like a table in a table).

Is there any way that I can modify the command to put all results from the individual select queries into one result that gets saved to the file? The input.csv contains several thousand rows, so I cannot make that into one query.

Comment: Remove the semicolon and append `union all` at the end of every line of `input.csv` except the last one.

Comment: Could have worked if my input csv was smaller, but I am getting ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded when I am trying that out.

Comment: If it is an one-of job then why not split it in a few parts and merge the results?

Comment: If the file only has one column, it is barely a CSV file, IMHO.

Comment: It is a one-of job but the csv is huge, we are talking 30k rows. Splitting it manually would be quite a lot of work.

Comment: 1) Your input file is not a csv file it is a script file 2) Go here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and look at `\pset format csv`